# MUnit site for Anypoint Studio

Tags: mule-esb, munit

I am trying to install Munit to my Anypoint Studio 4.1.0 (Mule server 3.5.2) using http://studio.mulesoft.org/r4/munit but it's failing with the below error

Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: MUnit Anypoint Studio Plugin 1.0.5.201603281940 (org.mule.tooling.munit.extension.feature.group 1.0.5.201603281940)
  Missing requirement: Munit 1.0.5.201603281940 (org.mule.tooling.ui.contribution.munit 1.0.5.201603281940) requires 'bundle org.mule.tooling.messageflow [5.4.3,5.5.0)' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: MUnit Anypoint Studio Plugin 1.0.5.201603281940 (org.mule.tooling.munit.extension.feature.group 1.0.5.201603281940)
    To: org.mule.tooling.ui.contribution.munit [1.0.5.201603281940]

Could you please help ?

Answer (score 0):

Install/upgrade to [munit r6](http://studio.mulesoft.org/r6/munit). Before updating munit from r4 to r6, uninstall previous versions of munit.

Comment: Before Updating Munit from r4 to r6, uninstall previous versions of MUNIT